# I want to build a PDF doc, using Glen K. Peterson's Pdf Layout Manager, but I'm stuck at building a table

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

I've decided to use Glen K Peterson's Pdf Layout Manager available on GitHub(https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager) to generate PDF documents with my app, I've imported the source files and the pom.xml dependencies and everything, it's working just fine.
The problem is, I'm trying to build a table in one of the documents I want to generate with a button click. I have no idea how to extract(use) the TableBuilder, as I'm getting the error message inside my JDeveloper IDE, that the class has private access.

Here's my code:

```
private void jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    try {
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER;
        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contents.beginText();
        contents.setFont(font, 14);
        contents.newLineAtOffset(50, 500);
        Coord coordinate = new Coord(10, 700);
        PdfLayoutMgr pageMgr = PdfLayoutMgr.newRgbPageMgr();
        LogicalPage locatieTabel = pageMgr.logicalPageStart();
        TableBuilder tabel = new TableBuilder(locatieTabel, coordinate); // Getting the error at this point
        contents.newLineAtOffset(10, 700);
        contents.showText(tabel.toString());
        contents.endText();
        contents.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MeniuTaburi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    jLabelAverstismenteVerMet.setText("<html><center>Datele au fost salvate cu succes!</center></html>");
}//GEN-LAST:event_jBtnSalvareVerMetActionPerformed
```

I thought of changing the type of access permission from private to public, for the TableBuilder, but I don't think, that's the way it's actually supposed to work...
Is there any other way, I can build the table I need, without resorting to changing the access modifier, inside the TableBuilder class??

Comment: Please share the exact error message and the exact location it is given for.

Comment: Error(3083,34): TableBuilder(com.planbase.pdf.layoutmanager.LogicalPage,com.planbase.pdf.layoutmanager.Coord) has private access in com.planbase.pdf.layoutmanager.TableBuilder
  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\mywork\mywork\DigitalizareLaboratorMetrologie\DigitalizareLaboratorMetrologie.jws
  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\mywork\mywork\DigitalizareLaboratorMetrologie\project\project.jpr
  /C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/mywork/mywork/DigitalizareLaboratorMetrologie/project/src/main/java/Components/Events/project/MeniuTaburi.java (3083,34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to use

```
TableBuilder tabel = new TableBuilder(locatieTabel, coordinate); // Getting the error at this point
```

But that constructor is private

```
    private TableBuilder(LogicalPage lp, Coord tl) {
        logicalPage = lp; topLeft = tl;
    }
```

I.e. you are not meant to use it. Unfortunately there also is no JavaDoc indicating what you should use instead. But looking at the `TableBuilder` source a bit beyond that constructor, you'll find immediately following this:

```
    public static TableBuilder of(LogicalPage lp, Coord tl) {
        return new TableBuilder(lp, tl);
    }
```

Thus, instead of your direct constructor call you should use this factory method:

```
TableBuilder tabel = TableBuilder.of(locatieTabel, coordinate);
```

Comment: Yup, this helped! Thanks! =)